# changing the format of a arbitrary date in php

Tags: php, date-formatting

I have a program where I want to enter an arbitrary date

```
2016-07-21 00:00:00
```

and I want to convert the format of the date to July 21 2016 00:00 GMT.

I started to write the following code in php:

```
#!/bin/php
<?php
   $date = "2016-07-21 00:00:00";
   echo date_format($date, 'F jS Y H:i:s');
?>
```

Now when I try to use this code, which I got from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php I get the following error messages:

```
PHP Warning:  date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string   given in /home/vrsops/server/work/experimental/exp.php on line 8
```

What does this mean?  How do I resolve this issue and be able to convert the date format to the one specified above?

Comment: ` $date = new DateTime("2016-07-21 00:00:00");`

Comment: https://eval.in/609672

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states `date_format()` requires a `DateTime()` object to be formatted. You gave it a string. If you want to use `date_format()` then you need to create use `date_create()` to create a `DateTime()` object.

```
<?php
    $date = date_create("2016-07-21 00:00:00");
    echo date_format($date, 'F jS Y H:i:s');
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/609674)

Comment: I gave the above method a try and get the following error:

Comment: If this answer helped you you can accept the answer as correct. Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to learn more about how this works.